# Add an app to windows registry from another project

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I am building an that I want to install on a computer and every time the user starts the computer the app will run automatically

in order for that i used the windows registry and entered my app :

`RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);`

`rkApp.SetValue("workForm", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());`

this works fine without the install
but when I add the installer project and put the lines there the installer project is added to the registry instead of my app
dose anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: That's because you use Application.ExecutablePath.  That's the installer when you put this code in a custom install action.  No need to write code to get this key created, a Setup project already supports setting registry values without code.